# What should be the file (folder) structure of images in a web site?

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on a project in ASP.Net that users can share photos about their trips. The users will have different trips, such as Tokyo - 11-01-2011, Sydney - 19-02-2012. So what is the best structure to store these images;

1. Storing all images in one folder called Users Trip Photos.
2. Creating specific folder for each user's photos.
3. Creating specific folder for each Trip.

My question is not just about this project. I wonder what should be the image structure in a web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to eventually hold a large number of images, you might want to look at restructuring your folder structure to speed up the image retrieval. Storing all your images in a single folder will eventually really slow things down when the system has to look through a list of >2K files on your file system.

One way I have seen it broken down is such:
Assuming each of your site user's has a unique id, you can use this to structure your folders. For example, a user's photos (id 12345) will be located in UploadedImages/1/2/3/4/5/12345. If you break out your folder structure this way, the system will only have to traverse a max of about 10 sub-folders in each folder to find the one it is looking for.

Is this feasible for your project?

Comment: yes, this maybe a good option.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar project, I keep my ASP.NET website images, ie logos, page header logos, anything to do with what isn't uploaded or in my case auto generated images (in my case graphs) in root/images.  I created a separate Directory called GlucoseProfiles in the root of my project for those images which get added to the site and it works great for me.  In your case, depending on image load as well (ie are you going to have < 100k .jpgs/etc on your site) I would just create a new image directory specific to the files that will be added to your site in a separate image folder.